# For loop repetition drawing trouble

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get a loop to draw a Christmas tree but the output is wrong, I've tried searching for the answer but i can't seem to find it and I'm stumped. The answer may be obvious but I've missed a lot and any help's greatly appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

const char blank = ' ';
const char leaf = '#';
const char wood = '|';
const int minSize = 4;
const int maxSize = 20;
int treeHeight;
int& getValidHeight(int&);
void drawALineOfFoliage(int);
void drawFoliage(int);
void drawTrunk(int);
void drawAXmasTree(int);
void drawAXmasTree(int treeHeight) {
getValidHeight(treeHeight);
drawFoliage(treeHeight);
drawTrunk(treeHeight);
}
int& getValidHeight(int& treeHeight) {
cout << ("Please enter the size of the tree (4-20):\n");
cin >> treeHeight;

while ((treeHeight < minSize) || (maxSize < treeHeight)) {
    cout << "ERROR: Invalid height! Enter the size of the tree (4-20):\n";
    cin >> treeHeight;

    return treeHeight;
}
}

void drawALineOfFoliage(int treeHeight) {


for (int x = 0; x < treeHeight; ++x){
    for (int y = treeHeight; y > x; --y){
    cout << blank;}
    for (int y = 0; y < x; ++y){
    cout << leaf;}}}

void drawFoliage(int treeHeight) {
int branchLine = 1;
do {
    drawALineOfFoliage(treeHeight);
    branchLine += 1;
} while (branchLine <= (treeHeight - 2));}

void drawTrunk(int treeHeight) {
int trunkLine(1), spaces;
while (trunkLine <= 2) {
    spaces = 1;
    while (spaces <= (treeHeight - 3)) {
        cout << blank;
        spaces += 1;}
    cout << wood << "\n";
    trunkLine += 1;
}
}



int main()
{
drawAXmasTree(treeHeight);
system("pause");}
```

the output  is just the Christmas tree deconstructed so all 
the levels are on the same line and  repeated several times

Comment: _'output is wrong'_ well show the right output and the output you got

Comment: OT: `int& getValidHeight(int& treeHeight)` why do you use references here? Simply read the input and return a value.

Comment: ah - it'd be good to add the tag 'homework' then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I took your sample code and gave it a run.

First of all, your styling and tabbing is inconsistent which can make the code really hard to read.

Next, your `drawALineOfFoliage` is actually drawing the entire tree without the trunk instead of just a line. Therefore you were missing a `cout << endl;` inside the main for loop after the other 2 nested for loop.

Begin edit:

EDIT: I forgot to talk about the half tree.

So in your existing code, it only prints half the tree. Something like this...

```
   #
  ##
 ###
####
```

Which is half a Christmas tree. To make it look similar to an actual tree, all I did was adding `*2` to the for loop that is responsible for printing the leaf. (You can also do `cout << leaf << leaf;` instead)

```
for (int y = 0; y < x*2; ++y) {
  cout << leaf;
}
```

End edit.

Since your `drawALineOfFoliage`is printing the tree already, in `drawFoliage`,

```
do {
    drawALineOfFoliage(treeHeight);
    branchLine += 1;
} while (branchLine <= (treeHeight - 2));
```

this do while loop is looping the amount of trees (again, without trunk) so it should be removed.

Now that we got the top part done, let's take a look at the trunk.

```
while (spaces <= (treeHeight - 3))
```

The `- 3` seems to came out of nowhere. And it is only printing one `|` per row which looks kinda weird so I removed the `- 3` and make it print 2 woods instead.

Now the output looks somewhat like this...

```
Please enter the size of the tree (4-20):
6

     ##
    ####
   ######
  ########
 ##########
     ||
     ||
```

Its alright but still weird. TLDR, I did some tweaking and got an end result like this...

```
Please enter the size of the tree (4-20):
7
       #
      ###
     #####
    #######
   #########
  ###########
 #############
      |||
      |||
```

Full code as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

const char blank = ' ';
const char leaf = '#';
const char wood = '|';
const int minSize = 4;
const int maxSize = 20;
int treeHeight;
int& getValidHeight(int&);
void drawALineOfFoliage(int);
void drawFoliage(int);
void drawTrunk(int);
void drawAXmasTree(int);

void drawAXmasTree(int treeHeight) {
  getValidHeight(treeHeight);
  drawFoliage(treeHeight);
  drawTrunk(treeHeight);
}

int& getValidHeight(int& treeHeight) {
  cout << ("Please enter the size of the tree (4-20):\n");
  cin >> treeHeight;

  while ((treeHeight < minSize) || (maxSize < treeHeight)) {
    cout << "ERROR: Invalid height! Enter the size of the tree (4-20):\n";
    cin >> treeHeight;
  }

  return treeHeight;
}

void drawALineOfFoliage(int treeHeight) {
  for (int x = 0; x < treeHeight; ++x) {
    for (int y = treeHeight; y > x; --y) {
      cout << blank;
    }
    for (int y = 0; y < x*2; ++y) {
      cout << leaf;
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
}

void drawALineOfFoliageOdd(int treeHeight) {
  for (int x = 0; x < treeHeight; ++x) {
    for (int y = treeHeight; y > x; --y) {
      cout << blank;
    }
    cout << leaf;
    for (int y = 0; y < x*2; ++y) {
      cout << leaf;
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
}

void drawFoliage(int treeHeight) {
  int branchLine = 1;
  drawALineOfFoliageOdd(treeHeight);
  do {

    branchLine += 1;
  } while (branchLine <= (treeHeight - 2));
}

void drawTrunk(int treeHeight) {
  int trunkLine(1), spaces;
  while (trunkLine <= 2) {
    spaces = 1;
    while (spaces <= (treeHeight - 1)) {
      cout << blank;
      spaces += 1;
    }
    cout << wood << wood << wood << endl;
    trunkLine += 1;
  }
}

int main() {
  drawAXmasTree(treeHeight);
  system("pause");
}
```

Note: I did not do any sort of cleanup so there are a lot of unnecessary codes in it. I just worked on top of what you have to provide you the best solution I got.

Comment: thank you, I'll make sure I work on my formatting to make it more comprehensible in the future. I've gone through what you said and the recommendations you made and i see where i was going wrong, thank you for your help its greatly appreciated!

Comment: @h3rcul35 Glad to be of help!

Answer (score 0):

Your `lineOfFoliage` seems to do lines for all `x < height`.  It seems to me that the basic structure of the foliage drawing code would be:

```
drawFoliage(height) {
  for(width = 0..height) cout << centeredLine(width);
}

drawCenteredLine(width) {
  return blanks + leafs;
}
```